# cordova-background-geolocation - lt is not working in Android lollipop

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working with device tracking function using ionic framework..

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-SampleApp

I tried above one..it's working fine on Android kitkat ...it's not working with lollipop ..it throws error code as **1 (Permission denied)**.

this error image
[image: error]

Comment: need some more clear explaination with you working code so only we can figure why you get alert 1

Comment: i download code from here** https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-SampleApp ** while getting geolocation ..it's throw this error

Comment: there is  any  alternative plugin like this(for tracking)

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: i put a alert in callback of error function it's throw 1 ..i refer this document for this error code ** https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/wiki/Location-Error-Codes **

Comment: It's premium version..so i need free version..

Answer (score 0):

you can use cordova geolocation plugin

use this code to install

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and use this code

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
```